# Found two representations of same collection exception?

Tags: java, hibernate

hello i have the following code :

```
@Entity
public class VirtualMeasure extends AbstractMeasure implements Record {

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE}, mappedBy 
= "virtualMeasureMyActionId.virtualMeasure")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
private Set<VirtualMeasureMyAction> vmMyAction;
}

@Entity
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "virtualMeasureMyActionId.virtualMeasure",         
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "virtualMeasureId")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "virtualMeasureMyActionId.myAction", 
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "myActionId")) })
public class VirtualMeasureMyAction implements Record {

/**
 * virtualMeasureViewId : VirtualMeasureViewId
 */
@EmbeddedId
private VirtualMeasureMyActionId virtualMeasureMyActionId;
}


@Embeddable
public class VirtualMeasureMyActionId implements Record {

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private VirtualMeasure virtualMeasure;


@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private MyAction myAction;
}
```

where i run i get this error [create] : javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found two representations of same collection: vmMyAction

Answer (score 2):

The problem is hibernate session is detecting that you have the same collection twice in the same session when you persist.

Take care to not duplicate setters and getters in your entities and use `merge()` intead of `update()`.

Comment: but the problem in create

Answer (score 1):

Here for vmMyAction you are providing `@OneToMany(mappedBy)` and `@Access` both. These are the two representations Hibernates tell you about in the exception. Hibernate doesn't support both at once.

```
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE}, mappedBy 
    = "virtualMeasureMyActionId.virtualMeasure")
    @Access(AccessType.FIELD)
    private Set<VirtualMeasureMyAction> vmMyAction;
```

Since as per the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-collection-extratype-indexbidir), `@Access` is now deprecated for `FIELD`, try above without the `@Access` annotation.

Comment: @AbdelmajidBahmed what methods do you get from `AbstractMeasure`? Or is `AbstractMeasure` too implements `Record`? If so, duplicated getters and setters will  too cause this exception.